# PostgreSQL - Query nested json in text column

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

My situation is the following

-> The **table A** has a column named **informations** whose type is **text**

-> Inside the **informations** column is stored a JSON string (but is still a string), like this:

```
{
    "key": "value",
    "meta": {
        "inner_key": "inner_value"
    }
}
```

I'm trying to query this table by seraching its informations.meta.inner_key column with the given query:

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE (informations::json#>>'{meta, inner_key}' = 'inner_value')
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  The input string ended unexpectedly.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: 
SQL state: 22P02
```

I've built the query following the given link: [DevHints - PostgreSQL](https://devhints.io/postgresql-json)

Does anyone know how to properly build the query ?

**EDIT 1:** 
I solved with this workaround, but I think there are better solutions to the problem

```
WITH temporary_table as (SELECT A.informations::json#>>'{meta, inner_key}' as inner_key FROM A)
SELECT * FROM temporary_table WHERE inner_key = 'inner_value'
```

Comment: At leasf one of the rows contains invalid JSON. This would not have happened if you had created a `json[b]` column to start with...

Comment: @GMB I agree with you. But the table is already created and running on production. Is there something I can do to solve this? EDIT: I solved with a workaround but I think that there are better aproaches to the problem

Comment: Basically you need to identify the offending values and fix or remove them.

Comment: If there are offending values, I think the workaround shouldn't work, right ? Correct me if I'm wrong